# How can i join 2 tables conditioned with 2 different columns in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here's some dumb example of i want to do.

Basically i need to join my "Person" table with my "Addres".
My country colcumn will be the strongest, i wanna join by it, but if my Person doesn't have a
country id i need to join it by City.

I've tried LATERAL join, but nothing has worked.

Table Addres:

| id | city | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 3 |
| 2 | 11 | null |

Table Person:

| id | name | city | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 3 | null |
| 2 | 11 | null | 2 |

Comment: Why not just join on `id`?  That seems to match.

Comment: The tables don't have an relation of ID it was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'OR' in your join statement:

```
select * from person p 
left join address a
on p.country = a.country
or p.city = a.city
```

Comment: If they are null, They will never match with the equal operator.